# Failing to get package via composer require

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I want to user this package [hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle) in my project which has dependency on [simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp dev-master](https://packagist.org/packages/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp)

If I try to add dependency like this:

`composer require hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master`

I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle[dev-master].
    - hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

If I `git clone` the [hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle](https://github.com/hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle) and use `composer update` simplesamlphp package is downloaded successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to composer.json. The usage of dev package versions imples that you need to have it. Use

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true
```

if you don't want it to affect other packages without strict version constraints.